# Sequelize update not committing / updating the database

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I am relatively new to using Sequelize and I have come across a problem I just can't fix! I am using the Sequelize update method, the query it produces seems to be correct and I have no code errors but my database isn't being updated! For example here is my code...

```
/*    
* @param {boolean} eula - true if accepted
* @param {object} user to whom dataset belongs.
* @returns {Promise} with the result of the action.
*/
      updateUserAcceptance(eula, user) {
        return db.sequelize.transaction(transaction =>
          db.User.findById(user.userId, {
            user,
            transaction
          }).then(selectedUser => {
            if (selectedUser !== null) {
              return db.User.update({
                EulaAccepted: eula,
                EulaAcceptedDate: Date.now()
              }, {
                where: {ID: user.userId},
                autocommit: true,
                user,
                transaction
              });
            }

            logger.warn('Unkown user or access not allowed');
            throw new Error('Unkown user');
          }))
          .then(() => {
            const result = {success: true};
            logger.info('UpdateEulaAccepted transaction successful');
            return result;
          }).catch(Sequelize.ValidationError, err => {
            const result = {success: false, validationError: true};
            result.error = ValidationHelper.ensureErrorFormat(err.errors);
            return result;
          }).catch(err => {
            const result = {success: false, errorMessage: 'Common Error'};
            logger.error('Unable to UpdateEulaAccepted to the database. Rolling back transaction');
            logger.error(err);
            return result;
          });
      }
```

This seems to be correct as I have no syntax errors, I have checked the parameters that are passed and these are correct and the error catching isn't triggered. I notice the following in the console

```
QUERY:  Executing (beba1d58-a408-4aa8-afa7-a2522a8f337f): UPDATE "User" SET "EulaAccepted"=true,"EulaAcceptedDate"='2018-08-10 11:19:54.933 +00:00',"ModificationDate"='2018-08-10 11:19:54.934 +00:00' WHERE (("DeletionDate" > '2018-08-10 11:19:54.933 +00:00' OR "DeletionDate" IS NULL) AND "ID" = 'aad025c8-2ecb-4a07-bd0d-e62476d25188')
```

This is correct and should I run it in pgAdmin 4 the sql is successful and updates my row... however in my app the query isn't set/executed despite outing to the console, no promise is returned and my application hangs then crashes! No warning or error is written to the console?I thought adding the `autocommit: true,` option but this just doesn't work!

Can anyone suggest how I can get this to execute or work? Maybe there is an extra option to force the execution? I'm totally lost why this isn't happening and must have spent 5 hours on this problem.

**Update** As asked here are the database fields of the table I am trying to update

ID - uuid

SelectedLanguage - character varying 10

Email - character varying 50

Name - character varying 50

CreationDate - timestamp with time zone

ModificationDate - timestamp with time zone

DeletionDate - timestamp with time zone

ClientID - uuid

CreatorID - uuid

ModifierID - uuid

TemporaryPassword - character varying 50

ChangePasswordToken - character varying 50

TokenExpirationDate - timestamp with timezone

EulaAccepted - boolean

EulaAcceptedDate - timestamp with time zone

isOrgAdmin - character varying 50

Comment: Will you please also post the fields of the table ?

Comment: Just added database table fields

Comment: > no promise is returned and my application hangs then crashes
You mean no promise is resolved or returned?

Also can you try to reinstall node_modules? Looks like maybe your `pg` package (`sequelize` dependency) might be corrupt.

Your code looks correct... Execution of other SQL queries is ok?

In PG admin try to run the SQL in transaction - that might be another source of error.

Comment: Hi there, no promise is returned. I also reinstalled my node_modules and upgraded my sequalize. I did run the SQL query that is written to the console in PG Admin and it works, it just doesn't seem to work in the app? The SQL code isn't executed in the app.